# I cant add a user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I have created an employee management system in Laravel and I want to add a user. Admin can edit, add, and delete the user. Edit and delete are fine but the problem with the additional user, the form it's not getting submitted to add the user gives me error!

this is create.blade.php file

```
@extends ('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Add Employee | Admin
@endsection

@section('content')


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Add  Employee.</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="/create" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                {{ method_field('PUT') }}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $users->name }}" class="form-control">               
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="{{ $users->lastname }}" class="form-control">               
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" value="{{ $users->phone }}" class="form-control">               
                </div>          
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email address</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email"  value="{{ $users->email }}"name="email" id="email">               </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Job Title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="jobtitle" value="{{ $users->jobtitle }}" class="form-control">               
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Department</label>
                    <input type="text" name="department" value="{{ $users->department }}" class="form-control">               
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Save </button>
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')

@endsection
```

dashboardcontroller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function registered()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('admin.register')->with('users', $users);
    }

    public function registeredit(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $users = User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('admin.register-edit')->with('users',$users);
    }

    public function registerupdate(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);
        $users->name = $request->input('name');
        $users->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
        $users->phone = $request->input('phone');
        $users->email = $request->input('email');
        $users->jobtitle = $request->input('jobtitle');
        $users->department = $request->input('department');
        $users->update();
        return redirect('/role-register')->with('status','Your Data is Updated');
    }

    public function registerdelete($id)
    {
        $users = User::findOrFail($id);
        $users->delete();

        return redirect('/role-register')->with('status','Your Data is Deleted');

    }


    public function index()
    {
        $users=DB::table('users')->paginate(10);
        //$users = User::all();
        return view('admin.dashboard',['users' => $users]);
    }


    public function department()
    {
        $users = User::all()->unique('department');
        return view('admin.department')->with('users', $users);
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $users = new User();
        //$user->save();
        return view('admin.create')->with('users', $users);


    }


}
```

web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin']], function  () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    });

    Route::get('/role-register','Admin\DashboardController@registered');

    Route::get('/role-edit/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registeredit');

    Route::put('/role-register-update/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registerupdate');

    Route::delete('/role-delete/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registerdelete');

    Route::get('/dashboard', "Admin\DashboardController@index");

    Route::get('/department', 'Admin\DashboardController@department');

    Route::get('/create', 'Admin\DashboardController@create');

});
```

It gives me this error:
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. I have searched for this error but I'm not getting any results. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just remove the   PUT method from there    {{ method_field('PUT') }}

Comment: it gives error again   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: <form action="{{url('/create')}}" method="POST">

Comment: public function create(Request $request)
    {
       echo "<pre>"; print_r($request->all());die();
        $users = new User();
        //$user->save();
        return view('admin.create')->with('users', $users);


    }

Comment: Route::post('/create', 'Admin\DashboardController@create');  make it post

Comment: oh i had it post,and now i changed that to get and it gives an empty array Array ( ) 
 but when i fill the form still doesnt work  ..                                    
  ErrorException
Creating default object from empty value

Answer (score 0):

Change your route get method to post

```
 Route::post('/create', 'Admin\DashboardController@create');
```

Also change your controller

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $users = new User;
    $users->name = $request->name;
    $users->lastname = $request->lastname;
    ......add other input rows here----
    $users->save();
    return view('admin.create')->with('users', $users);


}
```